# Transparency of the image captured by camera Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, transparency, augmented-reality

I am trying to do a AR project using unity. I doesn't have much experience in Unity and I am using this project to learn and understand a little better. In my project I have the device's **camera always connected** and that is projected in my device. 
I would like to understand if there is any way (or any propriety) of having my **real-time image transparent**. Like changing the transparency of what I see/ what it is captured.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can achieve partial transparency of camera preview by playing with OpenGL: after all, it's just a texture in your scene.